# Table valued parameter error parameter or variable has an invalid datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, table-valued-parameters

```
//Table valued parameter creation
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tblFactIds] AS TABLE(
[FactId] [int] NULL
//using TVP in SP,just declaring a var of type TVP which i created
DECLARE @FactIds As tblFactIds;//error: parameter or variable has an invalid datatype //tried by adding READONLY also
INSERT INTO @FactIds (FactId)
 SELECT * FROM Sampletable
```

Errors what am getting:Must declare the table variable @FactIds
Please help me out of this issues.

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tblFactIds] AS TABLE
(
    [FactId] [int] NULL
)
```

see the ending `)`? It creates a type. You use it only once, and the type "remains" (like a table or a view)

and you must execute it BEFORE doing the declare

Or you can put a `GO` in-between:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tblFactIds] AS TABLE
(
    [FactId] [int] NULL
)

GO

DECLARE @FactIds As [dbo].[tblFactIds]
```

so that the `CREATE TYPE` is executed.

Comment: @Annem Important: run only the `DECLARE TYPE`, then run the other part of your query

Comment: I have created TVP in a similar way but while posting question it has missed the braces

Comment: TVP is created already and am using it in SP,just by declaring the variable as a TVP datatype

Comment: @Annem Various possibilities... The default schema you are using isn't `dbo`, the type you created isn't in the `dbo` schema, there is no `[dbo].[tblFactIds]`. For the last two, check in the SQL Management Studio, Programmability->Types->User-Defined Table Types

Comment: Checked the schema it is append with dbo.

Comment: @Annem Then probably you have problems somewhere else: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/030f7/3